# Does numbers=autoenddot work in KOMA Script?

Tags: koma-script

The guide of KOMA-Script (version 2015-07-02) has described how does KOMA-Script handle the periods at the end of numbers.

According to:
[image]

and

[image]

Period should be added directly at the end of number in style like TEIL I, but omitted at the end of number in style like 1.1 or 1.1.1. However, it seems that it doesn't work...
Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    numbers=autoenddot,
    12pt,
]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\part{Lorem}
\section{ipsum3}
\subsection{dolor}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The output looks so:

[image]

Do I miss something or just misunderstand the description in the guide of KOMA-Script?

Comment: Yes, it works. As soon as a non-arabic numbering is active in the document, the aotodot is added to *all* sectional commands.

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I have just misunderstood the description in the guide. It actually says that if any roman numerals or letters are in the numbering, then the whole numbering system has periods at the end of number. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Johannes_B want to add an answer?

Comment: @clemens Done so finally.

Answer (score 1):

If the numbering scheme of sectional commands is purely arabic (1, 2, 3, ...) no `autodot` will be typeset.

If you add an appendix with alphabetic numbering, or set the document to use roman numbering (`part`s use it) the autodot will be set to *all* sectional units.

If you refer to a section in your document using `\ref`, the autodot is *not* typeset.